# changing a tag s href depends on entered value in it

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
$("a[class='sayfa']").attr('href', 'http://www.url.com/')
```

and using it to change href of

```
<a href="url" class="sayfa">Text-Entered-by-Script</a>
```

everything is ok with this part. the problem is i m using a script called list.js which fills content inside a div depending on class and listing them. script changing only Text-Entered-by-Script part not class or anything so i need to change href depending on Text-Entered-by-Script value something like

```
$("a[value='sayfa']").attr('href', 'http://www.url.com/')
```

but this 1 is not working ofcourse. 
thank you for your answers and here is the full code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="hacker-item1">
         <h3 class="name"></h3>

        <p class="desc"></p>
        <p class="createdDate"></p> <a href="url" class="sayfa">Text-Entered-by-Script</a>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="list.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        item: 'hacker-item1'
    };

    var values = [{
        name: 'Jonny',
        desc: 'Stockholm',
        createdDate: 'June 8, 2013 ',
        sayfa: '1'
    }, {
        name: 'Jonny',
        desc: 'Stockholm',
        createdDate: 'May 8, 2013',
        sayfa: '2'
    }, {
        name: 'sssssss',
        desc: 'eeeeeeeee',
        createdDate: 'June 20, 2013',
        sayfa: '3'
    }, {
        name: 'sssssss',
        desc: 'eeeeeeeee',
        createdDate: 'June 20, 2013',
        sayfa: '4'
    }];

    $("a[class='2']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/')
    $("a[class='3']").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
    $("a[class='1']").attr('href', 'http://www.youtube.com/');
    //    values.push({name : xml.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, desc : xml.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,createdDate : xml.getElementsByTagName("publishdate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue});
    var hackerList = new List('Div1', options, values);
    //alert(hackerList.items.length + '');
</script>
```

Comment: Well i solved my problem this way.
`{ name: 'Jonny', desc: 'Stockholm', createdDate: 'May 8, 2013' , page:'<a href="http://www.live.com/">1</a>' }` 

 but i still wonder if its possible to show entered text between opening and closing tags as a identifier for `<a>` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would select all the `<a>`-elements with the class `sayfa`, and for each of them, change the value of the href attribute to their text value. 
Is that what you are after?

```
$('a.sayfa').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).text());
});
```

Comment: no i already done that. but i want to change href depending on "Text-Entered-by-Script" value. the thing i want to do is when  script entering a value inside a tag want another one to read that value ("Text-Entered-by-Script" part) and give it a specific href depending on this value. source of problem is i cant change href part with list.js script, it just enters value between opening and closing tags thats all.

Comment: `$(this).text()` fetches the text value of the `<a>`-element, which is Text-Entered-by-Script, right? `$(this).attr('href','something')` sets the value of the href to 'something'. If you need 'something' to be something else based on the text value, you can set that with a switch and a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much all ok now.